# How Do You Use App Script to insert Blank Placeholder Data for Missing Cell Contents?

Tags: javascript

I have quite a few data inputs in a Google Sheet that are feeding a Google Doc via placeholders using App Scripts. When I run the below function I get the following error message "Exception: Invalid argument: replacement"

I believe that because a few of my replacetext calls have blank cells it doesn't replace them in the Google Doc.

What is required to replace the placeholder text in the Google Doc even if the contents of the cell are blank?

```js
function CreateRecommendations() {
  // This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step  
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('FileID');
  
  // This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderID')
  // Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Blueprint')
  
  // Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    // Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    // Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[0]) return;
    
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Recommendations: ${row[1]}` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
        
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Page Name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Page URL}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Primary Keyword}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{H1}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{Meta Title}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Meta Description}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Secondary Keyword 1}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Secondary Keyword 2}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 1}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 2}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 3}}', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 4}}', row[17]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 5}}', row[18]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 6}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 7}}', row[20]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 8}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 9}}', row[22]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 10}}', row[23]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 11}}', row[24]);
    body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 12}}', row[25]);

    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1).setValue(url)
    
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you verify the length of  `row`? To do so, add the line `Logger.log('row.length: ' + row.length);` at the start of the `rows.forEach` function and see what the output is in the execution log.

Comment: This is what I get: [21-01-23 11:03:30:167 EST] row.length: 20

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by including an OR blank statement (see below) within the body.replaceText field.

|| ""

Example: body.replaceText('{{Semantic Keyword 7}}', row[20]**|| ""**);

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with inserting a value from a blank cell. From [the `getValues()` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()):

```
Empty cells are represented by an empty string in the array.
```

An empty string is a valid argument to `replacetext()`.

However, [`sheet.getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) returns a variably sized 2-diminsional array, based on which cells are populated in the sheet.

**With a `row.length` of 20, the problem is that you're using invalid indexes (i.e. `> 19`).**

From [the MDN Array documentation](https://gist.github.com/chuckx/4a9e557fa1dcd16bb4ded5ef91f0e6c1):

> Using an invalid index number returns undefined.

For example:

```js
let example = ['foo', 'bar'];

console.log('example.length: ' + example.length);
console.log('valid index (0): ' + example[0]);  // logs "foo"
console.log('invalid index (2): ' + example[2]);  // logs "undefined"
```

---

A potential problem with the approach you've taken (i.e. `row[index] || ""`) is that [any value that evaluates to false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) will be replaced with an empty string. Of particular concern in the context of spreadsheets would be the number value `0`. There's a chance that values such as this could be inadvertently replaced with an empty string.

A more robust (and slightly easier to maintain) approach would be to separate the spreadsheet data mapping and document text replacement. Then you can easily perform more error checking in the latter without a lot of cumbersome code repetition.

```js
function CreateRecommendations() {

  // ... skip unchanged portion ...

  const templateMap = {
    // '<template placeholder>': <sheet column>
    '{{Page Name}}': 1,
    '{{Page URL}}': 2,
    '{{Primary Keyword}}': 3,
    '{{H1}}': 7,
    '{{Meta Title}}': 8,
    '{{Meta Description}}': 10,
    '{{Secondary Keyword 1}}': 12,
    '{{Secondary Keyword 2}}': 13,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 1}}': 14,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 2}}': 15,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 3}}': 16,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 4}}': 17,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 5}}': 18,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 6}}': 19,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 7}}': 20,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 8}}': 21,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 9}}': 22,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 10}}': 23,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 11}}': 24,
    '{{Semantic Keyword 12}}': 25,
  };
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {

    // ... skip unchanged portion ...
    
    // Replace the repeated body.replaceText() calls with this.
    for (const t of Object.keys(templateMap)) {
      const column = templateMap[t];
      // Only extract the value if the column exists.
      const value = column < row.length ? row[column] : '';
      body.replaceText(t, value);
    }

    // ... skip unchanged portion ...
  })
}
```